# JavaScript not working inside iframe in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I am using an iframe that loads a page with a form. The form action is overridden using javascript. The javascript form action is working in IE and Chrome. But in Firefox the javascript is not working and the form is getting submitted to http://example.com/index.php

The code is given below:

```
<script language='Javascript' type='text/JavaScript'>
function submitFunction() {
document.Insert.action = 'http://example.com/page2.php';
return true;
}
</script>

<FORM ACTION='http://example.com/index.php' METHOD='POST' ENCTYPE='x-www-form-urlencoded' name='Insert' id='Insert' autocomplete='off' onsubmit='return(submitFunction())'>

<input name='num' SIZE='45' MAXLENGTH='45'>

<input name='Submit' type='submit'/>
</FORM>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
document.Insert.action = 'http://example.com/page2.php';
```

to

```
document.getElementById('Insert').action = 'http://example.com/page2.php';
```

But it seems a little strange to change the action URL of the form in the onsubmit. You could as well have it defined from the start.

Comment: I want to hide the url so I am loading it inside an iframe.The submit button will show the form action url on mouse hover.The issue is when it is loaded inside an iframe.

Comment: @user1690835: Allowing the user to see what's going to happen is a **Good Thing**. Strongly recommend focussing on useful functionality, not hiding things from the user.